# database roles name convention

Tags: sql-server, naming-convention

i want to ask if there is any name convention for sql server database roles, what is best practise or what i should follow. We have databases and a lot of people and i want to suggest some rules. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default roles all have db_ and then something descriptive of the roles permissions. I would stick with that.

Comment: Hi @James Anderson I wonder if it would be better to have a different prefix so you can distinguish the customized from original. Like it is with stored procedure.